# mqtt library which support softwareSerial on arduino uno with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, softwareserial

I am using ESP8266 and Arduino with `SoftwareSerial`. My requirement is to use MQTT protocol with it. So I am using an MQTT library named `pubSubClient` but the problem is it doesn't support `SoftwareSerial`. Could anyone tell me how can I use MQTT protocol with it?

```
#include 
#include 
SoftwareSerial esp(2, 3); // RX, TX 
PubSubClient client(esp);
```

The error I get is: `no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(SoftwareSerial&)`

Comment: Are you using http://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the following information:

* Why can't you use softwareSerial? What error do you get?
* Why cant you use the main UART (serial) port?
* What daughter board are you using for the ethernet?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. PubSubClient has nothing at all to do with serial in any form whatsoever. It interfaces with the standard Arduino Client class. What you should be looking for (and maybe asking about) is an ESP8266 library that supports SoftwareSerial and presents the standard Arduino Client interface.

Comment: #include 
#include

SoftwareSerial esp(2, 3);// RX, TX
PubSubClient client(esp);

Error is:no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::PubSubClient(SoftwareSerial&)'

Comment: As @Majenko says, you need an Arduino PubSubClient that supports SoftwareSerial - you are trying to pass in a SoftwareSerial object which is not a `PubSubClient`. A brief google failed to find any SoftwareSerial clients but there is a ESP8266 PubSubClient here : https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the ESP8266 WiFi module with `pubSubCient`, you need a library that interfaces with the module with the usual AT commands, while presenting an Arduino `Client` interface on the surface. A while back, I found [this library](https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp) after a great deal of searching. It supports `SoftwareSerial` as well as `HardwareSerial` objects. Its ESP8266 interface provides the standard `Client` methods of `write()`, `read()`, `connected()`, etc. There are some issues, of course, but its the best I've found so far. You can pass the created `Client` object to the `pubSubClient` constructor and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do - but thought I would offer this since I just spend some time on getting my esp8266 to act as a wifi shield for my arduino.  Basically I wanted to subscribe to an mqtt channel and send the payload to my arduino.  So the esp8266 connected to a broker, upon reading a message, it would simply write it via serial to the arduino (I used software serial on the arduino side so I could use the standard serial for debugging).  If it helps, check out http://mganis.blogspot.com for the details

--Matt